# Slide image to out of screen

Tags: android

How can i slide an image to top-left of screen??

Please see my image

[image]

This animation should be slow

i tried with following code but does not work!

```
public Animation fromAtoB(View v, float fromX, float fromY, float toX, float toY, int speed, AnimationListener l)
{
    Animation fromAtoB = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, fromX, Animation.ABSOLUTE, toX, Animation.ABSOLUTE, fromY, Animation.ABSOLUTE, toY );
    fromAtoB.setDuration(speed);
    if(l != null)
    {
        fromAtoB.setAnimationListener(l);               
    }
    v.setAnimation(fromAtoB);
    v.startAnimation(fromAtoB);
    return fromAtoB;
}
```

Please advise , thanks